# Set Selected value after php foreach

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

Currently I fill a select box with the following code:

```
<select name="klas_jaar" value="{jaar_id}">
    <?php foreach ($jaren as $jaar):?>
        <option value="<?=$jaar->jaar_id?>"><?=$jaar->schooljaar?></option>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
```

The value set is the same id as a option's value.. however it doesn't put the requested value as selected when going to this page.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`select` tags don't have a `value` attribute.  Instead, you have to drop a `selected` attribute in the appropriate `option`.

```
<select name="klas_jaar">
    <?php foreach ($jaren as $jaar):?>
        <option value="<?=$jaar->jaar_id?>"<? if($jaar->jaar_id == $selected_jaar_id) echo " selected"?>><?=$jaar->schooljaar?></option>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php foreach($city as $row){?>

    <option value="<?php echo $row['city_uid'];?>" <?php if($row['city_uid'] == $leaddetails[0]['city']){echo "selected";}?>><?php echo $row['city_name']?></option>

  <?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**in laravel**

```
<option
        @if(count($jaren)==1 && $key === $jaar->category_id) ) selected
        @endif  value="{{$key}}">{{$value}}
    </option>
```